# RangeValidator to revalidate when a new value is entered

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a asp RangeValidator of type money. When I enter a value that is below or above the min/max value I get an error message (onblur) as expected. However, when I re-enter a new value within the min/max, the error remains. The page does validate and lets me pass but I want the validator to reevaluate onblur. Is this possible without writing a custom solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this on the TextBox `onblur='Page_ClientValidate();'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me a lot of time.